# TypeError: Cannot read property 'items' of undefined

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am trying to develop a webpage using Angular 8 where I get a response from a REST API in JSON format on passing the request id and I want to bind that data in a table that I created in HTML. I am getting the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'items' of undefined.

Below is the my `items.component.html`

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<input class="in" type="text" (keyup)="onKeyUp($event)">
<button class="btn" (click)="getResults()">Search Request</button>
<br>
<div class="container">           
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="user_request_id">Request ID</th>
        <th class="asset_name">Asset Name</th>
        <th class="generated_path">Generated Path</th>
        <th class="match_percentage">Match Percentage</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr  *ngFor="let item of _items.items"> 
        <td>{{item.user_request_id}}</td>
        <td>{{item.asset_name}}</td>
        <td><a href="">{{item.generated_path}}</a></td>
        <td>{{item.match_percentage}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Below is the `items.component.ts` file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { GetItemsService } from '../get-items.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-items',
  templateUrl: './items.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./items.component.css']
})
export class ItemsComponent implements OnInit {
  public RequestID : String;

   _items:any;
   id:String='';
   items:any;

  constructor(private service: GetItemsService) { }


  ngOnInit() {
  }
  onKeyUp(event:any){
    this.id=event.target.value;
   } 

  getResults(){
    this.service.getData(this.id).subscribe((data) => {
      console.log(data)
      this._items = data
        });
  }
}
```

Below is the service file.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class GetItemsService {
  constructor(private httpClient:HttpClient) { }

  public APIurl = 'sample.com';

  getData(iD):Observable<any>{
    return this.httpClient.get<any>(this.APIurl+iD);
  }
}
```

And below is the JSON file.

```
{
    "items": [{
        "user_request_id": 10,
        "asset_name": "XXX",
        "generated_path": "tbd",
        "match_percentage": "14.02"
    }],
    "first": {
        "$ref": "https://ords/xxdcode/xxdcoderest/xxdcodesuggestasset/10"
             }
}
```

Comment: what is the output of console.log(data)....Check the network console and check the APi is returning the json or not

Comment: {items: Array(1), first: {…}}
first: {$ref: "https://ords/xxdcode/xxdcoderest/xxdcodesuggestasset/10"}
items: Array(1)
0:
asset_name: "OES_CLOUD_REP002_Invoice_Print_Report"
generated_path: "tbd"
match_percentage: "14.02"
user_request_id: 10
__proto__: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
__proto__: Object

This is the output of json along with the above error

Comment: You are probably  missing the error argument in the getResult method. Try my answer

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the first error argument in the getData call

```
 getResults(){
    this.service.getData(this.id).subscribe((err,data) => {
        if (err) {
             alert("Error");
              return;
        }
      this._items = data
        });
  }
```

Comment: I am getting the below error
'''
Parameter 'data' implicitly has an 'any' type, but a better type may be inferred from usage.ts(7044)
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 5, '(observer?: PartialObserver<any>): Subscription', gave the following error.
'''

Comment: In your tsconfig.json add this "noImplicitAny": false to "compilerOptions":{} it will work

Comment: Still getting the first error even after adding this

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container" *ngif="_items">           
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="user_request_id">Request ID</th>
        <th class="asset_name">Asset Name</th>
        <th class="generated_path">Generated Path</th>
        <th class="match_percentage">Match Percentage</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody *ngif="_items.items.length!=0">
      <tr  *ngFor="let item of _items.items"> 
        <td>{{item.user_request_id}}</td>
        <td>{{item.asset_name}}</td>
        <td><a href="">{{item.generated_path}}</a></td>
        <td>{{item.match_percentage}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi OAH, i am getting another error now "TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined". And i am unable to initialize _items the way you suggested, it is throwing an error "Cannot find name _items."

Comment: yeah if you don't init _items, it will show this error, so we remove .length!=0 , i updated the  answer